# my openldap use mysql as backend but it hvae no auth to add user

Tags: openldap

i use my rootdn to login phpLDAPadmin and success,but i cant add user in phpLDAPadmin ,i think it a problem with openldap have no auth to write, error is

Could not add the object to the LDAP server.
LDAP said:  Server is unwilling to perform
Error number:   0x35 (LDAP_UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM)
Description:    The LDAP server refused to perform the operation.

this is my slapd.conf

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema


# Define global ACLs to disable default read access.

# Do not enable referrals until AFTER you have a working directory
# service AND an understanding of referrals.
#referral       ldap://root.openldap.org

pidfile         /var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/slapd.args

# Load dynamic backend modules:
# modulepath    /usr/libexec/openldap
# moduleload    back_mdb.la
# moduleload    back_ldap.la

# Sample security restrictions
#       Require integrity protection (prevent hijacking)
#       Require 112-bit (3DES or better) encryption for updates
#       Require 63-bit encryption for simple bind
# security ssf=1 update_ssf=112 simple_bind=64

# Sample access control policy:
#       Root DSE: allow anyone to read it
#       Subschema (sub)entry DSE: allow anyone to read it
#       Other DSEs:
#               Allow self write access
#               Allow authenticated users read access
#               Allow anonymous users to authenticate
#       Directives needed to implement policy:
#access to dn.base="" by * read
#access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
#access to *
#       by self write
#       by users read
#       by anonymous auth

# 允许cn=Mitya Kovalev,dc=example,dc=com读写权限
access to *
  by dn="cn=Mitya Kovalev,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by * read

#
# if no access controls are present, the default policy
# allows anyone and everyone to read anything but restricts
# updates to rootdn.  (e.g., "access to * by * read")
#
# rootdn can always read and write EVERYTHING!

#######################################################################
# SQL database definitions
#######################################################################

database        sql
suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Mitya Kovalev,dc=example,dc=com"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoid.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
rootpw          {SSHA}arSDeFAtUBPiz14lwlcdu0NXMWgjMNec

# SQL configuration
dbname ldap
dbuser ldap
dbpasswd 123456
has_ldapinfo_dn_ru no
subtree_cond "ldap_entries.dn LIKE CONCAT('%',?)"
insentry_stmt   "INSERT INTO ldap_entries (dn,oc_map_id,parent,keyval) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"


# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND 
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
# Indices to maintain
```